# Exit PHP script w/o error

Tags: php, performance, exit

I have a PHP script that registers approximately 20 functions. Ideally it'd be loaded with `require_once`. I want make it so that even if somehow it does get loaded more than once, it wouldn't try to re-register the functions. I could wrap each declaration in `!function_exists`, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way. (Or do you think 20 calls to `!function_exists` is negligible?) I tried using `exit` but that causes an error. Is it possible to exit w/o throwing an error ?

```
if ( /* already loaded */ )  { 
    /* leave gracefully */
}  

/* declare ~20 functions */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!defined('ALREADY_LOADED')) {
    define('ALREADY_LOADED', true);
    // rest of your code goes here

}
```

This checks to see if a constant `ALREADY_LOADED` is defined, and if it is not, it defines the constant and will do whatever else you want.

After it's been run once, the constant will be defined, and it will not run a second time.

I suggest using a more descriptive constant name than `ALREADY_LOADED`.

Comment: Cool yea I thought about using a `global` but I think the constant is even easier.

Comment: Just remember not to use the same constant name in different files. ;)

Comment: this is often refered as an include protector in other languages ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think using OOP is the most practical way
Can be used as a class with static functions

```
class SimleClass{
    public static function func1($arg){...}
}
```

use it
SimpeClass::func1($arg);

or sigleton

```
class SimleClass{
    protected static $_instance=null;
    private function __construct(){...}
    public static function getInstance(){
       if(is_null(self::$_instance)
            self::$_instance=new SimpleClass();
       return self::$_instance;
    }
    public  function func1($arg){...}
}
```

use it
SimpleClass::getInstance()->func1($arg);

and how to connect it think itself
can  use include_once

and can implement the autoloader class

```
function myClassLoader($className){
 include_once "/lib/$className.php";
}
spl_autoload_register(myClassLoader);
```

=============================================================
for more concrete answer requires more data.
Perhaps your application, you can rearrange to get the more logical structure

Comment: Thx-I like the idea. I'm trying to make it so the functions are exposed globally, meaning they'd be callable with `func1($arg)` rather than `SimpeClass::func1($arg)` What's the best way to do that?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the relevance of this problem, divorced from context.
Explain, why it is not convenient solution based on the classes?
Maybe find another way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you as an author don't require it more then once, (or use `require_once()` consistantly) there shouldn't be a problem about re-registering functions.

As for exiting without an error, try [`die()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php).

Answer (score 1):

I would try not to redeclare functions in first step (here require more than once).
Doing 20x function_exists() does not cost anything, only some time writing and wrapping ;)
Perhaps you could try to use classes/methods instead.

Comment: My original idea was to use a class but I was having trouble getting it to work. I tried wrapping it in `class RAVE { /*declarations*/ }` and then after that I put `$rave = new RAVE();` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`function_exists` is no bad.

You can write your php script files in the following manner.

```
/* file1.php */
if(!defined('FILE1')) {
define('FILE1', 1);
/////////////////////////
// PUT file contents here.

/////////////////////////
}// file.php finished.
```

Now you can include this file as many time as you want here and there. Nothing will be redefined again.